# Use of significant figures in lab report calculations

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, statistics

I am currently doing a lab report that involves multi-step calculations. The values σ(mean, visual) and σ(mean, auditory) are calculated to be 0.004051s and 0.004917s. Since the number of trials (27 and 30) are involved in the calculations, do I use two sig fig on σ(mean, visual) and one for σ(mean, auditory) or are the number of trials considered given numbers and should be ignored?

Another related question, if I was to continue onto the next step of the calculations which include these two values, do I use the unrounded version or the rounded version (example: 0.004051 or 0.0041)?

Comment: The number of trials won't affect the number of sig figs. The number of trials doesn't have uncertainty to it.

Answer (score 2):

You should always round at the end of your calculations. Ideally, you would not plug in any numbers until you get to your final step, because computers/calculators/etc. have finite precision and will do some rounding internally also. So your most accurate number will always happen if you wait until the last possible moment to plug things into the equation.

Regarding the number of significant digits, it's been a really long time since I've done it so this may not be the "textbook" answer (which may be the one your instructor is looking for). However, the number of tests you ran has no uncertainty to it. You know you ran 27 trials. You didn't run 27.00001 or 26.999995 or anything else. You know it exactly. So I wouldn't consider that as a factor in the number of digits. I'd consider it a constant, just like if I were to average two numbers, I wouldn't say that I only have 1 significant digit because I divided by 2.

So, wait until the end to plug in and don't use rounded values for further calculation. And don't round based on "constants" if they are actually determinate numbers with no uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote but I don't have enough rep yet :D

Answer (score 1):

## Reporting Values

You report average values from two sets of measurements $\langle V\rangle_j$. You must also state the standard uncertainty (error) of the value $\delta V_j$. Your report must be given as

$$ \langle V \rangle \pm \delta V$$

## Defining Significant Digits

A standard rule of thumb is to report the standard uncertainty with at most two significant digits. By example

- $\pm 1.245 \rightarrow \pm 1.2$
- $\pm 0.01245 \rightarrow \pm 0.012$
- $\pm 1245. \rightarrow \pm 1.2 \times 10^3$

The next step is to round the average value according to the significant digits in the uncertainty. By example

- $98.765 \pm 1.245 \rightarrow 98.8 \pm 1.2$
- $9.8765 \pm 0.01245 \rightarrow 9.877 \pm 0.012$
- $98765. \pm 1245. \rightarrow 98.8 \pm 1.2 \times 10^3$

## Further Insights

Some reports will demand that uncertainties can only have one significant digit, no more. Some reports will provide additional rules on how to determine whether the uncertainty should have only one or may have two significant digits depending on whether the last digit is 4 or less.

All counting numbers are infinitely precise and have an infinite number of significant digits. We make 30 measurements, not 29.99999999999999999$\bar{9}$ measurements. Alternatively, we cannot expect to be twice as precise by doing 29 measurements (your incorrect statement of having only two significant digits) as opposed to when we do only one more measurement at 30 (your incorrect statement of having only one significant digit).

Answer (score 0):

The significant digits will depend on the accuracy of the numbers you used to calculate sigma. That is the visual and auditory values. Your mean can not be 0.004051 if your values are +/- 0.1 for example.